# Krige in 3 dimensions in R in gstat: is it possible?

Tags: r, geospatial, kriging

Okay, so  I know it is not possible to do variograms in the vertical direction in gstat, because of something with the z coordinates.

However, I'm wondering if it is possible to **krige** in 3 dimensions.  If it isn't possible to get a variogram in the vertical direction, I do not understand how it is possible to **krige** in 3 dimensions, since kriging depends on a variogram model.  Is this possible?

Finally, when I do the following, the kriging throws an error, and I have a feeling it might have something to do with not having an adequate 3d model:

```
varY = var(training$Y)   # sill of log(K) values 
Ih = 60    # horizontal range
Iy = 30    # vertical range 
e = Ih/Iy # anisotropy ratio (I_horizontal/ I_vertical)
mod <- vgm(psill = varY,'Exp',Ih, anis=c(0,90,0,1,e)) # axisymetric model with e*I_x = e*I_y = I_z

# define kriging domain 
x <- sample(seq(0,300,by=5),10,replace=FALSE)
y <- sample(seq(0,300,by=5),10,replace=FALSE)
z <- sample(seq(0,30,by=0.5),100,replace=TRUE)
Y <- sample(seq(-3.0,-0.01,by=0.001),100*10*10,replace=TRUE)

grid = data.frame(x=rep(x,times=length(x)),y=rep(y,each=length(y)))

mydata = data.frame(x=rep(x,each=10),y=rep(y,times=10),z=z,Y=Y)
ok_3D <- krige(formula=Y~1, locations=~x+y+z, data=mydata, newdata=grid, model=mod)
```

But it throws this error:

```
Error in .subset(x,j) : only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts
```

Is this because it is not possible to define a variogram in the vertical direction in gstat?  Or is this another issue?  Thanks.